# How do I handle sub and sup while using scrapy in the scenario below?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract questions from the HTML format shown below

```
<li > 
    <h3 > Number Theory - Factors < /h3 >
    <p lang = "title" > How many factors of 2 < sup > 5 < /sup > * 3 < sup > 6 < /sup > * 5 < sup > 2 < /sup > are perfect squares?< /p >

    <ol class = "xyz" >
        <li > 18 < /li >
        <li > 24 < /li >
        <li > 36 < /li >
        <li > 8 < /li >
    < / ol >
    <ul class="exp">
        <li class="grey fleft">
            <span class="qlabs_tooltip_bottom qlabs_tooltip_style_33" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <span>
                    <strong>Correct Answer</strong>Choice (B).</br>24
                </span> Correct answer
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="primary fleft">
            <a href="factors_3.shtml">Explanatory Answer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey1 fleft">Factors - Perfect Squares</li>
        <li class="orange flrt">Medium</li>
    </ul>       
</li>
```

My question can be extracted from  which I did with an XPath expression *normalize-space(//p[@class="soln"])*

The XPath expression extracts and gives me this text
**How many factors of 24 * 53 * 74 are odd numbers?**

How do I get the question with the sub and sup inside it?
**Possibility 1:** I get the question as "How many factors of 2<sup>4</sup> * 5<sup>3</sup> * 7<sup>4</sup> are odd numbers? without losing the sub or sup"

**Possibility 2** I get the question as "How many factors of 2^4 * 5^3 * 7^4 are odd numbers? Basically I dont want to change the meaning of the question?"

Comment: Can you explain in clear word what is happening and what you want. The description provided by you is not seem relevant to html added by you

Comment: Is there any way I can get the question as it is without changing the meaning?

Comment: I updated my question @Tuks

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite pretty, but we can pre-replace `<sup>` with `^` and remove the `</sup>` left-over:

```
In [1]: response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace("<sup>", "^").replace("</sup>", ""))

In [2]: response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@lang="title"])').extract_first()
Out[2]: u'How many factors of 2 ^ 5 * 3 ^ 6 * 5 ^ 2 are perfect squares?'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'n not familier with screpy still i can add some code sample written in java which helps you

```
// get inner html of your question with `sup` or `sub` tags

String question = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@lang = 'title'] ")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

// Replace the tags with symbols

String newQuestion = question.replace("<sup>", "^").replace("</sup>", "");
System.out.println(newQuestion);
```